# Determine array by value and order

Tags: javascript

Given an array which will always contain `two` or `three` values. I need to determine the index of the biggest value and add attribute to it lets say `main`. Then depending on the order set `left` to the first small value and `right` to the second small value. (Careful for `array6`)

There must always be one `main`.

It's easy to determine the biggest value like:

```js
var array1   = [0.25, 0.75];        // desired result: ['left', 'main']
var array2   = [0.75, 0.25];        // desired result: ['main', 'right']
var array3   = [0.25, 0.50, 0.25];  // desired result: ['left', 'main', 'right']
var array4   = [0.50, 0.25, 0.25];  // desired result: ['main', 'left', 'right']
var array5   = [0.25, 0.25, 0.50];  // desired result: ['left', 'right', 'main']
var array6   = [0.40, 0.10, 0.50];  // desired result: ['left', 'right', 'main']
var array7   = [0.50, 0.50];        // desired result: ['left', 'main']


index1 = array1.indexOf(Math.max.apply( Math, array1 ));
index2 = array2.indexOf(Math.max.apply( Math, array2 ));
index3 = array3.indexOf(Math.max.apply( Math, array3 ));
index4 = array4.indexOf(Math.max.apply( Math, array4 ));
index5 = array5.indexOf(Math.max.apply( Math, array5 ));
index6 = array6.indexOf(Math.max.apply( Math, array6 ));

console.log(
    'index1: ', index1,
    'index2: ', index2,
    'index3: ', index3,
    'index4: ', index4,
    'index5: ', index5,
    'index6: ', index6
);
```

But how can I achieve the rest of desired result without using now 100 if else to determine?

**Update**
The total sum of the array values will always be `1`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible (or readable) in a short one-liner. Instead, I would write a function `function (probabilities) { return ['left', 'right', 'main']; }` and use if/else blocks. When the function is working, you can try to optimize and combine similar code blocks.

Comment: what should be the output for `[0.50, 0.25, 0.75]`? is it `[left, right, main]` simply? but `0.50` is bigger than `0.25` and according to your question it will be `[right, left, main]`

Comment: oooh @KoushikChatterjee good question! I'll update the question as I mentioned it wrong there! It should be `['left', 'right', 'main']`

Comment: @user3151902 yep something like that would be nice but how to know which ones are already used?

Comment: `var array6   = [0.50, 0.25, 0.50];` has to be `['left', 'right', 'main']` or can it be `['main','left', 'right']` also whats the desired result for `[0.50, 0.50, 0.50]`?

Comment: @UlugToprak updated the question based on your comment. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I wrote a function that will solve your purpose with minimal `if...else`

```js
var array1   = [0.25, 0.75];        // desired result: ['left', 'main']
var array2   = [0.75, 0.25];        // desired result: ['main', 'right']
var array3   = [0.25, 0.50, 0.25];  // desired result: ['left', 'main', 'right']
var array4   = [0.50, 0.25, 0.25];  // desired result: ['main', 'left', 'right']
var array5   = [0.25, 0.25, 0.50];  // desired result: ['left', 'right', 'main']
var array6   = [0.40, 0.10, 0.50];  // desired result: ['left', 'right', 'main']
var array7   = [0.50, 0.50];        // desired result: ['left', 'main']

function transformArr(numArr) {
    var res = ['left', 'right'];
    maxIdx = numArr.lastIndexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, numArr));
    res.splice(maxIdx, numArr.length === 2, 'main')
    return res;
}

console.log('Result 1', transformArr(array1));
console.log('Result 2', transformArr(array2));
console.log('Result 3', transformArr(array3));
console.log('Result 4', transformArr(array4));
console.log('Result 5', transformArr(array5));
console.log('Result 6', transformArr(array6));
console.log('Result 7', transformArr(array7));
```

This code is written on the considering that arrays will contain **either 2 or 3** numbers.

Comment if anything is not clear.

Comment: @caramba I have edited my answer removing the `if` else. please check.

Answer (score 1):

You could splice at the index of the first max value from the right, the value `main` and delete a value, if the length of the array is two.

```js
function x(array) {

    function getMax(r, a, i, aa) {
        return a > aa[r] ? i : r;
    }

    var r = ['left', 'right'];
    r.splice(array.reduceRight(getMax, array.length - 1), array.length === 2, 'main');
    return r;
}

console.log(x([0.25, 0.75]));        // ['left', 'main']
console.log(x([0.75, 0.25]));        // ['main', 'right']
console.log(x([0.25, 0.50, 0.25]));  // ['left', 'main', 'right']
console.log(x([0.50, 0.25, 0.25]));  // ['main', 'left', 'right']
console.log(x([0.25, 0.25, 0.50]));  // ['left', 'right', 'main']
console.log(x([0.40, 0.10, 0.50]));  // ['left', 'right', 'main']
console.log(x([0.50, 0.50]));        // ['left', 'main']
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents:

```
function transformArr(arr){
  let indexes = arr.map((_, i) => i);
  indexes.sort((i1, i2) => arr[i2] - arr[i1]);

  let mainI = indexes[0];
  indexes = indexes.map(x => {
    return {index: x, atLeft: x < mainI, value: arr[x]};
  });

  let res = {"main": indexes[0].value};
  // let names = ['left', 'inner left', 'inner right', 'right'];
  let names = ['left', 'right'];
  for(let i = 1; i < indexes.length; i++){
    let val = indexes[i];
    let name = val.atLeft ? names.shift() : names.pop();
    res[name] = val.value;
  }
  return res;
}
```